# c# picturebox bitmaps

Tags: c#, bitmap, picturebox

I have a picturebox that upon request, I save the current display to a bitmap.

My question is, how do I then load that same bitmap to the picturebox?

Thanks.

EDIT:

The only relevant code is:
    pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(test1,pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);

The picture box contains graphics that I have written 'freehand' using the mouse.  So you can use the mouse to write directly onto the screen when the left mouse is pressed.

Comment: Wait, your picturebox displays a bitmap, upon request saves it to disk, and you want to display to bitmap that was saved to disk?  Are you clearing the picturebox when you save it?

Comment: Where do you store this bitmap? What are you doing with it? Some relevant code might help us understand better..

Comment: No...at first it is a standard piturebox, and I then save it's contents to a bitmap.

Comment: code added..thanks.  The bitmap for this purpose is just stored in memory...called test1 in my code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign any image to the picture box that you want during run-time. Just set the [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image.aspx) property of the picture box to the picture you want to be displayed.

For example, to display an image in a picture box from a file on your hard drive, you could use something like:

```
myPicBox.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\savedimage.bmp");
```

Or, your edit suggests that you have a bitmap object in memory that you want to display in the picture box. In that case, it's a simple matter of assigning that bitmap object to the `Image` property:

```
myPicBox.Image = test1;  //(where test1 is your bitmap object in memory)
```

**Edit:** Just in case you want to save the bitmap object that you created in memory to disk so that you can reload and use it later, check out the [`Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.save.aspx) method of the `Bitmap` object:

```
test1.Save("C:\savedimage.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the picturebox should have an Image property that you can simply use to assign the Bitmap to.